# applying a function once to all fields of the same class in different files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

so I have this function `validateDate('.date')` which basically puts a date mask over any input fields which have `date` as a class. There is a php and javascript file for each page. How can I implement this function once rather than in each separate page .js file?

The validation function is in a separate .js file called validations.js. Also, I tried calling the function in my main file (under $(document).ready).

Comment: if you have ONE validations.js then how  "There is a javascript file for each page." ? can you be more clear

Comment: @epipav for example, I have Playermanager.js and Teammanager.js, but rather than implementing `validateDate` in each, I was thinking of creating the function in a separate file and run it once if it's possible..

Basically I was thinking of separating validation logic from the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a setup like this:

```
php file#1
    <script src="some-javascript-file1.js"/>
    <?php
    //some php code
    ?>

php file#2
    <script src="some-javascript-file2.js"/>
    <?php
    //some php code
    ?>
```

and so on... Then all you need to do is create a central js file that has your javascript functions that apply to more than one file!

```
php fileN
    <script src="some-javascript-fileN.js"/>
    <script src="/your/file/path/to/validations.js"/>
    <?php
    //some php code
    ?>
```

As always, if your script file depends on other libraries, they must be loaded before validations.js  Usually, when you have code that applies to more than one page, it should be centralised into a file that is called on all the pages that need it.  I'd be very suprised if you *had* to have a separate js file for every single php page!

Answer (score 0):

create a distinc js file, called validation.js.
in that file, implement your "masking" operation in a function.

```
(function(){
    //there goes your masking implementation
})();
```

this, will execute your function immediately when you include it in your html.add this script to all of your htmls using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
```

and voila